# ASP.NET MVC - Multiple controller types were found that match the URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, attributerouting

Using ASP.NET MVC 5.2 with attribute routing. I have 2 actions in separate controllers:

```
public class AccountController
{
   [Route("login")]
   public ActionResult Login()
   {
   }
}

public class HomeController
{
   [Route("{category}")]
   public ActionResult Category(string category)
   {
   }
}
```

When I run it, I get an error `Multiple controller types were found that match the URL. This can happen if attribute routes on multiple controllers match the requested URL.`

`category` dynamic parameter in Category action is something that is checked against DB in the action and there are a lot of possible values so I don't think I can use route constraints to include all possible options, it's also a string, so something like `category:int` is not an option.

I think I also cannot use `Order` in routing since those actions are in different controllers.

I know I can change the route for `Category` action to be something like `[Route("category/{category}")]` but I'd prefer to not do that. What's the best way for me to go about it so both `/login` and `/{category}` work?

Comment: With attribute routing? to get the paths you want they wont work. `login` will be mistaken for a `category`

Comment: so there is no workaround with attribute routing? I'm fine with using conventional routing for `Category` action if it helps fix my problem.

Comment: Yes using convention for category will work for that scenario. But given that there was no indication of other routes there is no way for me to tell if it will affect other routes

Comment: I have a whole bunch of routes in multiple controllers that only use a single routing segment like so `/login`, `/register`, `/terms` etc. So using conventional routing, would I need to put it under `routes.MapRoute( name: "Default",...`?

Comment: you can use the attribute routes for the single segment routes and then have the rest go to category  via convention since attribute routes are registered before. category would however become a catch-all route given its single parameter

Comment: thanks! Yeah I guess catch-all route would be the last resort. I'm reading I can do custom route constraints, so I can specify something like this `[Route("{category: existsInDB}")]` where existsInDB is a custom constraint...  maybe I can make it work

Comment: That will work once designed correctly. Route constraints is the best bet if you want to keep it all in attribute routing and not ,mix convention based routes.